# Is there a subgroup $H$ of $G$ of index $p$, where $p$ is the smallest prime dividing $|G|<\infty$?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

To be clear: I'm not asking whether $H$ is normal in $G$ or not.
It is well-known that if such $H$ exists, then $H$ is normal in $G$, which is out of my interest right now.

But can we say that such $H$ always exists? (for any finite group $G$?)

Comment: Not every finite group $G$ has non-trivial normal subgroup, so your statement can't be true.

Comment: as a generalization to @Dovahkin's answer, $A_n$ ($n\geq 4$) cannot have a subgroup of index 2. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1501876/show-a-n-has-no-subgroups-of-index-2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[$A_{4}$ does not have a subgroup of order $6$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/582658/a-4-has-no-subgroup-of-order-6)

To elaborate , $A_{4}=2^{2}\cdot 3$

Since it does not have a subgroup of order $6$ . We cannot say that it has a subgroup of index $2$ which is the smallest prime dividing the order of $A_{4}$.