# $S_4$ has only a subgroups of order 12?

Tags: abstract-algebra

If N is a subgroup of $S_4$ and |N|=12 , N is normal in $S_4$ because N has index 2. N has also an element of order 3 for the Cauchy's lemma.Why N has all the 3-cycles of $S_4$?

I want to prove $S_4$ has only a subgroups of order 12

Comment: Yes? Was that actually your full question?

Comment: do you want to prove that there is only one such subgroup? if yes, see this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27024/a-n-is-the-only-subgroup-of-s-n-of-index-2

Comment: the professor gave us that tip to follow

Answer (score 1):

All $3$-cycles are conjugate. If $N$ is normal and contains a $3$-cycle, then $N$ contains all $3$-cycles. It is well known that $A_n$ is generated by the $3$-cycles for $n\ge 4$. This means that $N \supseteq A_4$ and so $N = A_4$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to look at it:

Since $N$ is normal, and it has an element of order $3$, it contains a $3$-cycle, and thus every $3$-cycle. For example, if $(1\ 2\ 3) \in N$, then taking $g$ to be the map:

$g(1) = a\\g(2)= b\\g(3) = c$

(and sending $g(4)$ to "whatever's left")

we have $g(1\ 2\ 3)g^{-1} = (a\ b\ c) \in N$.

So $N$ contains at least $9$ even permutations (the $3$-cycles and the identity), that is:

$9 \leq|N \cap A_4| \leq 12 = |N|$.

But $N \cap A_4$ is surely a subgroup of $S_4$, and thus has order dividing $24$.

Of the numbers $\{9,10,11,12\}$ only $12|24$, so we conclude $|N \cap A_4| = 12$, that is: $N \subseteq A_4$.

But the only subgroup of $A_4$ that has order $12$ is $A_4$ itself, so $N = A_4$.