# Number of index $2$ subgroups in $S_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups, normal-subgroups

I'm trying to solve a problem from my Group Theory course. It goes like this:

> Being $S_n$ the symmetric group of order $n$. Find the number of index
> 2 subgroups of $S_n$.

I'm not pretty sure how to start. I guess it would have something to do with the normal subgroups of $S_n$, since any index two subgroup of a group $G$ is normal to $G$. But I don't know how to compute this number of subgroups, I just know that $|S_n|=n!$. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Just to be clear, that "duplicate" proves a stronger statement than you are asking for, at least for $n≥5$. The cases $n<5$ are "easy" to handle separately.

Comment: @lulu No, I think it doesn't. I know that any index 2 subgroup is normal, but I don't know if any normal subgroup has index two. Is this last condition true?

Comment: SInce the duplicate proves that there are no normal subgroups (other than $A_n$ of course) then it instantly follows that there are no subgroups of index $2$ (other than $A_n$)  As I said, the duplicate is a lot stronger than what you are asking.

Comment: In any case, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27024/a-n-is-the-only-subgroup-of-s-n-of-index-2) is a more exact duplicate (and it works for all $n$).