# Why is $[S_n:K]=2$ and $A_nK=S_n$ a contradiction?

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups

I'm trying to prove that $A_n$ is the only subgroup of index $2$ in $S_n$ by a contradiction argument, which have led me to the equality

$$A_nK=S_n,\tag{$*$}$$

where $K$ is a subgroup of index $2$ in $S_n$, *distinct from $ A_n$*. Why is $(*)$ a contradiction (if it actually is)?

Comment: We need more details about your proof.  It's possible for a finite group to have distinct subgroups of index $2$, so there must be something about your particular construction that leads to the contradiction.

Comment: If we are allowed to use the fact that $A_n$ is simple for $n \ge 5$ then we know that $A_n$ has no subgroup of index $2$, so this cannot happen, since this would imply $|A_n:A_n \cap K|=2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This reasoning is possible.

Since every cycle of odd length lies in $K$ (why?) and $(123)(234)=(12)(34)$ it follows that $A_n\leq K$.

Comment: Yes that's better than my solution in the comments, because there is no need to assume the simplicity of $A_n$.